# Spring MVC building a lazy-init bean not called, property ref bean issue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been looking into everything I know about Spring and on the forums a lot but I can't figure out this issue. I have an xml of lazy-init beans. I understand how the lazy-init works, as every other bean is only resolved when called. 
One bean however, will always be created, regardless of it actually being called. If I comment out a single property line of the bean, the bean does not get created, obviously meaning that property must be getting called somewhere, but it just isn't.

```
    <property name="discriminator" value="${review.queue.discriminator}"/>
```

That is the line that calls itself automatically so my handful of questions are:
Does setting a value in the property cause it to automatically be called?
What else would I be able to do to make sure that this line will not get called?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I solved my own problem. If I set a default value within the value, it did not build the bean. I changed that line to:

```
    <property name="discriminator" value="${review.queue.discriminator:notARealDiscriminator}"/>
```

and It refused to build the bean after that.